# Obter a frequencia a partir de um vetor no dominio da frequencia

Tags: java, matemática, áudio

Estava olhando os seguintes tópicos:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674877/how-to-get-frequency-from-fft-result

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649003/jtransforms-fft-in-android-from-pcm-data

Neles é explicado como realizar a transformada para poder obter a frequência de um som. Ele usa uma biblioteca que toma como entrada um vetor double no domínio do tempo e retorna um vetor no domínio da frequência usando o metodo `realForwardFull()`;
Então se eu tenho um vetor no dominio do tempo (audioDataArray), cada posição desse vetor tem um valor de magnitude e ao fazer a transformada, o vetor fica no dominio da frequencia:

```
DoubleFFT_1D.realForwardFull(audioDataArray);
```

1. No domínio do tempo cada posição é a magnitude e o índice indica o `tempo(x=índice; y = magnitude)` pelo que pude entender. No domínio da frequência,  depois de aplicar a transformada, os valores de cada posição do vetor continuam a ser a `magnitude(y)`? O que representa os índices?

Para encontrar a frequência fundamental ele faz a conta a seguir para cada posição do vetor e compara para ver qual tem maior valor (magnitude):

```
Magnitude = sqrt(re*re + im*im)
```

Achando o índice que tem maior magnitude ele faz seguinte conta para achar a frequência fundamental:

```
Frequency = Fs * i / N
```

where:

```
Fs = sample rate (Hz)
i = index of peak
N = number of points in FFT (1024 in this case)
```

2. Não entendi essa conta: Por que para achar a frequência fundamental tem que multiplicar o índice pela taxa de amostragem e dividir pelo numero de posições do vetor?

Answer (score 5):

Vamos lá gafanhoto lol

A transformada de Fourier vai lhe retornar unidades reais e imaginárias, é muito importante que você entenda de [números complexos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_complexo) e [matemática discreta](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matem%C3%A1tica_discreta).

Respondendo suas dúvidas:

> No domínio do tempo cada posição é a magnitude e o índice indica o
>   tempo(x=índice; y = magnitude) pelo que pude entender. No domínio da
>   frequência, depois de aplicar a transformada, os valores de cada
>   posição do vetor continuam a ser a magnitude(y)? O que representa os
>   índices?

`Y` = retorno dos valores computados pela transformada de Fourier, valores dos componentes espectrais, estes valores podem ser utilizados para achar a Magnitude, para isso é preciso extrair a parte real e imaginária dos valores retornados pela transformada, para encontrar a magnitude a partir dos valores da transformada é necessário calcular a raiz quadrada da parte real ao quadrado mais a parte imaginária ao quadrado...

```
(sqrt((real(FFT).*real(FFT))+(imag(FFT).*imag(FFT))))
```

Portanto o `Y` inicial não é a magnitude o `Y` é o retorno da transformada, a magnitude você encontrou com a equação acima, você ainda pode utilizar uma equação derivada da mostrada acima e converter os valores em decibéis, também pode utilizar os valores da transformada para calcular diferentes tipos de descritores, ou ainda encontrar a fase do sinal analisado.

`X` = Índices de cada componente espectral calculado, isso quer dizer que quando você olha um plot das magnitudes no domínio da frequência, você está observando todas as frequências que compõe seu sinal e suas respectivas magnitudes, portanto `x = período`, isso é muito importante, `a transformada de Fourier de um sinal periódico gera um espectro discreto no domínio da frequência`, ou seja, é extremamente útil para fazermos análises em  sinais que se repetem em um intervalo de tempo `T`, claro pode ser utilizado para encontrar padrões de frequências em qualquer tipo de informação/dado.

O índice `X`(pense como período) possui uma ordem de resolução que depende totalmente do tamanho da amostra analisada pela Transformada de Fourier, se você enviar uma amostra de tamanho igual a `4096` terá uma ordem de resolução de `2.4414e-04 =  0.00024414062`, em suas aulas básicas de física você deve se lembrar que a frequência e o período de uma onda é igual `f = 1/T` aplicando teremos  `1/4096 = 0.00024414062`, quanto menor a ordem de resolução, mais preciso será a periodicidade...

> Não entendi essa conta: Por que para achar a frequência fundamental
>   tem que multiplicar o índice pela taxa de amostragem e dividir pelo
>   numero de posições do vetor?

Com o valor da taxa de amostragem nas mãos + o número de amostras do vetor enviado para Fourier é possível saber quais são as frequências correspondentes em cada `X`

Portanto cada índice corresponde a uma frequência, vamos imaginar que você gere `4096` componentes espectrais e que a taxa de amostragem do seu áudio seja de `44100hz`, isso te daria uma ordem de resolução = `44100/ 4096 = 10,7666015625hz` ou se preferir `(1/4096) * 44100 = 10,7666015625hz`

Isso quer dizer que a precisão de cada componente está perto de `11hz` de diferença, a grosso modo você pode estar errando uma frequência na exatidão de `11hz` em cada um dos `4096` índices/componentes, antes disso você tem que saber que existe um teorema chamado Nyquist, ele define que para reconstruir um sinal com mínimo de perda de informação a frequência amostrada deve ser igual ou maior a duas vezes a maior frequência do espectro desse sinal, se nossa frequência de amostragem é `44100hz` então a maior frequência possível dentro deste sinal vai ser `44100/2=22050hz`, mas e ai como saber quais frequências eu vou ter em cada componente espectral da série fourier:

```
  índice/componente 1 -> 10,7666015625000hz

  índice/componente 2 -> 21,5332031250000hz

  índice/componente 3 -> 32,2998046875000hz

  índice/componente 4 -> 43,0664062500000hz

  índice/componente 5 -> 53,8330078125000hz

    …

    …

    …

  índice/componente  2047 -> 22039,2333984375hz

  índice/componente  2048 – > 22050hz
```

Opa chegamos no componente `2048` que é a máxima frequência permitida pelo teorema de Nyquist.

isso te lembra alguma coisa `Fs * i / N` ? É a equação derivada para saber qual é a frequência correspondente de um determinado índice, quer tentar ?

```
Fs = 44100
N = 4096
i= ?
```

vamos aplicar na fórmula:

```
44100*1/4096 = 10.7666
44100*2/4096 = 21.5332
44100*3/4096 = 32.2998
44100*4/4096 = 43.0664
```

Então imagine agora que o pico da magnitude aconteceu no índice número `90`, então de novo usando a fórmula `44100*90/4096 = 968.9941hz`

Não sei se você sabe, mas o método acima não é nada recomendado na utilização de afinadores e captura de frequências,  o pico da magnitude nem sempre compõe a percepção correta de uma determinada frequência isso se deve ao fenômeno psicoacústico, mas esse é outro assunto, existem diferentes métodos de capturas de frequências no domínio do tempo e no domínio da frequência.

**Respondendo as dúvidas dos comentários**

> Pode me recomendar algum livro ou curso online para me inteirar mais
>   sobre o assunto. Quero me aprofundar sobre esse assunto de
>   processamento de áudio

Aqui no Brasil não conheço cursos para engenharia de som, fora existe universidades conceituadas nesse assunto, o principio para manipulação de áudio que aprendi foi no meu curso de engenharia da computação, estudando análise de sinais na matéria de processamento digitais, o curso de engenharia elétrica aborda o tema de maneira mais completa, existe alguns cursos em áudio que eu recomendo na internet, [princípios de engenharia de som](https://www.coursera.org/learn/audio-engineering) e [processamento de sinais voltado para música](https://www.coursera.org/learn/audio-signal-processing) se prepare para entender de matemática...

> Qual a equação para encontrar os valores em decibéis a partir do Y
>   inicial que foi retornado pela transformada?

```
20 * log10((sqrt((real(FFT).*real(FFT))+(imag(FFT).*imag(FFT)))))
```

> Se x é o período, então por exemplo, um vetor de 4096 posições com
>   dados capturados a uma taxa de amostragem de 44100 terá em cada
>   posição dados referente a 0,092879818 segundos (4096/44100
>   =0,092879818 segundos) . Então se eu fizer 1/ 0,092879818 = 10,7666 Hz, seria a frequência de cada posição do vetor sendo 10,7666 Hz a
>   menor e 44097,536 Hz (10,766 * 4096) a maior frequência que posso
>   guardar?

para um sinal amostrado em `44100hz` e com número de pontos `4096` a menor frequência é de `10,7666hz` e maior será `22050hz`

```
índice/componente  2048 – > 22050hz
```

por causa do teorema de Nyquist

> Então se a ordem de resolução é de aproximadamente 10,766 Hz, ele não
>   conseguiria distinguir uma frequência de 450 Hz de uma de 445Hz?

Exatamente, existem maneiras de amenizar esse problema aplicando interpolação parabólica dos índices vizinhos.

> Não entendi por que você dividiu 1/4096 e achou essa ordem de
>   resolução. Essa ordem de resolução é em relação a frequência ou ao
>   período?

Frequência e Período são equivalentes, se você tem o período de um sinal você consegue saber a frequência, se você tem a frequencia de um sinal você consegue saber o período...

> Com o vetor no domínio do tempo teria como eu saber quais frequências
>   tem menor db e eliminá-las do vetor para se obter maior precisão na
>   identificação da frequência com a transformada de fourier? Quais
>   opções eu tenho para melhorar a identifiação da frequencia?

Improvável de fazer isso, mas você pode capturar frequências diretamente no domínio do tempo, existem diversos algoritmos para encontrar pitch/frequência sem a necessidade de utilizar a transformada de fourier, algumas técnicas, `autocorrelation`, `ASDF`, `AMDF` `YUN` eu gosto muito da AMDF escrevi um código e deixei open source no [tarsos](https://github.com/JorenSix/TarsosDSP/blob/master/src/core/be/tarsos/dsp/pitch/AMDF.java), só fiz o básico e não implementei alguns segredos nele, mas você pode usar como base para fazer o seu, alias os especialista e eu também prefiro algorítimos no domínio do tempo para encontrar frequências em áudios monofônicos.  Existem outros tipos de algoritmos no domínio da frequência que são melhores do que apenas achar o pico da magnitude, procure por `subharmonic summation`, `Cepstrum` e `autocorrelação no domínio da frequência` alguns deles possuem patentes e ninguém demonstra a `mágica` em código aberto;

> Você disse que esse não é o melhor modo de se obter a frequência.
>   Quais outros modos eu poderia utilizar, além desse que determina a
>   frequência através da magnitude. Porque realmente eu vi um
>   espectrograma de uma flauta e mesmo tocando uma nota, por exemplo,440
>   Hz, a maior magnitude foi do segundo harmônico , 880Hz. Isso aconteceu
>   com duas notas que não me recordo agora. Ou seja, realmente a
>   frequência da maior magnitude não representa a frequência da nota

Utilize algoritmos mais inteligentes do que somente pegar o pico da magnitude, procure pelos algoritmos indicados na resposta anterior, o erro que você descreveu da flauta é conhecido como erro de oitava, os algoritmos citados acima também podem sofrer do mesmo problema, um detector de frequência esperto consegue lidar com isso, alias esse tipo de problema é complicado de contornar, é tão complicado que existe patentes descrevendo como pegar o pitch(frequência) correto, uma maneira de fazer isso é observar se o maior pico possui submúltiplos inteiros com uma certa magnitude equivalente do maior pico, se um sinal for periódico o período com pico maior(P) vai possuir outro pico com uma amplitude equivalente em 2*P...(guarde esse segredo com carinho rsrs)

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado mesmo por responder...achei que ninguém ia responder...obrigado mesmo...ajudou demais.Percebi que você domina o assunto e eu estou apenas começando como pode perceber...rsrs. Pode me recomendar algum livro ou curso online para me inteirar mais sobre o assunto. Quero me aprofundar sobre esse assunto de processamento de áudio.

Comment: Qual a equação para encontrar os valores em decibéis a partir do Y inicial que foi retornado pela transformada?

Comment: Se x é o período, então por exemplo, um vetor de 4096 posições com dados capturados a uma taxa de amostragem de 44100 terá em cada posição dados referente a 0,092879818 segundos (4096/44100 =0,092879818 segundos) . Então se eu fizer 1/ 0,092879818 = 10,7666 Hz,  seria a frequência de cada posição do vetor sendo 10,7666 Hz a menor e 44097,536 Hz (10,766 * 4096) a maior frequência que posso guardar?

Comment: Então se a ordem de resolução é de aproximadamente 10,766 Hz, ele não conseguiria distinguir uma frequência de 450 Hz de uma de 445Hz?

Comment: Não entendi por que você dividiu 1/4096 e achou essa ordem de resolução. Essa ordem de resolução é em relação a frequência ou ao período?

Comment: Com o vetor no domínio do tempo teria como eu saber quais frequências tem menor db e eliminá-las do vetor para se obter maior precisão na identificação da frequência com a transformada de fourier? Quais opções eu tenho para melhorar a identifiação da frequencia?

Comment: Você disse que esse não é o melhor modo de se obter a frequência. Quais outros modos eu poderia utilizar, além desse que determina a frequência através da magnitude. Porque realmente eu vi um espectrograma de uma flauta e mesmo tocando uma nota, por exemplo,440 Hz, a maior magnitude foi do segundo harmônico , 880Hz. Isso aconteceu com duas notas que não me recordo agora. Ou seja, realmente  a frequência da maior magnitude não representa a frequência da nota.

Comment: @L.J tentei responder as dúvidas na minha resposta dá uma olhada lá