# JS WEB Audio API getByteFrequencyData() range

Tags: javascript, api

Estou usando o AnalyserNode para analisar a intensidade de cada frequência de um som, assim posso fazer um visualizador. O problema é que o `analyser.getByteFrequencyData()` retorna a intensidade das frequências de 20Hz a 20KHz comprimidos em um array de 255 posições, e gostaria de filtrar essas frequências entre, por exemplo 30Hz e 600Hz, pra isso eu pensei em modificar a própria API ou fazer uma nova função usando a `analyser.getByteFrequencyData()` como base e filtrar essas frequências. Ou eu precisava de uma solução que obtivesse o mesmo array analisando uma faixa de frequência menor que pudesse ser fora da API.

Eu gostaria de saber se tem como eu acessar o código dessa API ou pelo menos saber o funcionamento interno dela para poder replicar ou modificar.

Edit:

Na documentação da API temos o segunite:

> The frequency data is composed of integers on a scale from 0 to 255.
> Each item in the array represents the decibel value for a specific frequency. The frequencies are spread linearly from 0 to 1/2 of the sample rate. For example, for 48000 sample rate, the last item of the array will represent the decibel value for 24000 Hz.

Como na documentação mostra, as frequências são distribuídas de 0Hz até a metade do valor da taxa de amostragem, então eu poderia simplesmente diminuir a taxa de amostragem para diminuir a range de análise, mas o problema é que a análise fica muito lenta.

Comment: Achei a pergunta OK e votei para reabri-la, mas recomendo você [edit] e adicionar uma descrição do que você precisa fazer, pois pode ser que não seja realmente necessário uma mudança nesse nível.

Comment: votei para reabrir tbm, em teoria não tem q filtrar nada, só cortar o seu array nos componentes espectrais correspondentes ...

Comment: edite a pergunta e coloque seu código ...

Comment: nem precisa fazer isso é só vc cortar o array nos componentes corretos @LinuxMen

Comment: Imagine que você tem 255 barrinhas na tela, e quer que elas representem de 0Hz até 255Hz mas você tem um array de 255 posições que analisa as frequências de 20Hz até 20KHz. Não é tão simples assim.

Comment: claro que é simples, cada barra representa uma resolução espectral baseado no tamanho do FFT do seu código e do samplerate, com isso vc sabe qual a frequência correspondente a cada posição do array, um arr de 255 posições poderá ser calculado para saber a frequência, por isso pedi o seu código na perguntar, se puder coloque seu código precisamos saber se esse tamanho de 255 tá usando o Nyquist, aqui 1 resposta d como calcular a frequência de cada posição do array [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/249250/obter-a-frequencia-a-partir-de-um-vetor-no-dominio-da-frequencia/253278#253278)

Comment: Os FFT's funcionam bem com potência de 2, eu não sei se a implementação que o JS usa funciona bem com tamanhos de FFT fora desse padrão, mas se vc quer 255 pontos entre 30 e 600 hertz vc poderia fazer uma FFT de tamanho exato `21400` respeitando o teorema de nyquist vc teria `21400/2= 10700`  pontos válidos, mas agora vc pode cortar o array na posição `13` na qual equivale a frequência de 30hz `round(1/(48000/30/(10700*2)))` e na posição `268` na qual equivale a freq 600hz, `round(1/(48000/600/(10700*2)))` isso te daria uma representação de 255 =`268-13=255` barras para representar suas freqs

Comment: já q sua pergunta não foi reaberta dá pra tentar te dar um norte nos comentários mesmo kkk, resumindo td depende da ordem de resolução que vc quer e quantas barras vc precisa e se esse tamanho da FFT vai funcionar em tempo real ou o tempo que demora para calcular o espectro, 21400 pontos não é pouca coisa não heim pode ser que vc tenha q testar se tiver trabalhando com representação em tempo real, esse parâmetros te dão uma ordem de resolução em `2.24` hertz, para fazer um spectrum analyser tá mais que bom rsrs ...